# Immediate seg fault when running ros node

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am new to ROS and I followed the directions for creating/making/running ros packages, but I get an immediate seg fault.

Here is what i did:

1. cd ~/ros_workspace
2. roscreate-pkg begtut std_msgs rospy roscpp
3. rosmake begtut
4. created talker.cpp from the tutorials and saved to src
5. added rosbuild_add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp) to CMakelists.txt
6. make
7. run roscore
8. rosrun begtut talker

I get "Segmentation fault" written to the screen

What am I missing?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12541/immediate-seg-fault-when-running-ros-node/) by [bobby](https://answers.ros.org/users/1613/bobby/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2012-01-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bobby](https://answers.ros.org/users/1613/bobby/) on 2012-01-06**:
Yes, it build no problem.

**Comment by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on 2012-01-06**:
Did you verify that the code was copied completely correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I figured it out.  Thanks for those who looked at my question.
I looked at the core dump file and saw that it was crashing in the boost threads.
I apparentlty have 2 boost libraries installed.
I think the ros install put another one in my system.

I went ahead and removed this version, and rebuilt my program.
Now it runs fine.

Thanks.

---

Originally posted by [bobby](https://answers.ros.org/users/1613/bobby/) with karma: 26 on 2012-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1